# 14.04, can I set switcher to operate on only the windows in the current display?

Tags: 14.04, unity, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, application-switcher

Running two monitors on my Ubuntu machine. I'm wondering if theres a way to set it so that alt-tabbing only switches between windows on the display that is currently active (the one my mouse is on). For example it gets annoying when I have seperate Chrome windows on both monitors, and alt-tabbing to one doesn't work when the other is open. I already poked around CompizConfig and didn't find what I needed. Any ideas? Maybe a different switcher that has that capability?